# Adding a new row on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Why I couldn't add a new row on pandas ?

```
data="""lname    fname   rno_cd    eri_cd
0    CRUISE   TOM     E         1
1    DEPP     JOHNNY  Y         0
2    DICAPR   LENARDO Nan       1
3    PITT     BRAD    Nan       1
4    MOST     JEFF    A         0
5    HANKS    TOM     Nan       1
6    BRANDO   MARLON  C         1
7    WILLIAMS ROBIN   F         1
8    DOWNEY   ROBERT  B         1
9    PACINO   AL      E         1"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(data.decode('UTF-8')),delim_whitespace=True )


df.loc[-1]= ['2','3','4','4']
```

I am getting an error whenever I try to excute the code.

I tried also:

```
df.loc[len(df)+1]
```

Comment: `loc` uses index label indexing, -1 and `len(df)+1` does not exist hence the error, for integer based indexing use `iloc`, also if you repeatedly appending rows this will be horribly inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.iloc` attribute:

```
df.iloc[-1] = []
```

More [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer).

Comment: Thanks!. For future reference, I could resolve that using 'concat' using a new df2.